# flex-shrink only the widest parts to some percentage, then shrink equally

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Imagine there's some breadcrumb bar - a line with various count of links, each link has ellipsis, and it should shrink if overflow.

Overflow should be smart - if there're 5 links, and 2 links are much wider than others, they have to be shrinked to 20%, and 3 short links should stay as they are.

If one link is much wider, and the rest 4 links are short, and they fit, then no shrink should happen. The widest link should not shink to 20% if the overall width is enough.

I'm trying different approaches but could not find one that fits these (natural) requirements. Is it possible to achieve without JavaScript?

I tried various combinations of flex-basis & min/max width, but no success yet:

https://jsfiddle.net/kasheftin/5k31fr4u/

```css
.breadcrumbs {
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0 0 50px 0;
  padding: 5px;
}

.breadcrumb-separator {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.ellipsis {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.breadcrumb1 {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

.breadcrumb2 {
  flex: 0 1 25%;
}

.breadcrumb2 {
  flex: 0 1 50%;
}

.breadcrumb4 {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  max-width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="breadcrumbs">
  <a href="#" class="breadcrumb1 ellipsis">
    SomeLongTitleGoesHereAndItsTooWideToFit
  </a>
  <div class="breadcrumb-separator">&raquo;</div>
  <a href="#" class="breadcrumb1 ellipsis">
    Short
  </a>
  <div class="breadcrumb-separator">&raquo;</div>
  <a href="#" class="breadcrumb1 ellipsis">
    Short
  </a>
  <div class="breadcrumb-separator">&raquo;</div>
  <a href="#" class="breadcrumb1 ellipsis">
    Short
  </a>
</div>

<div class="breadcrumbs">
  <a href="#" class="breadcrumb2 ellipsis">
    SomeLongTitleGoesHereAndItsTooWideToFit
  </a>
  <div class="breadcrumb-separator">&raquo;</div>
  <a href="#" class="breadcrumb2 ellipsis">
    Short
  </a>
  <div class="breadcrumb-separator">&raquo;</div>
  <a href="#" class="breadcrumb2 ellipsis">
    Short
  </a>
  <div class="breadcrumb-separator">&raquo;</div>
  <a href="#" class="breadcrumb2 ellipsis">
    Short
  </a>
</div>

<div class="breadcrumbs">
  <a href="#" class="breadcrumb3 ellipsis">
    SomeLongTitleGoesHereAndItsTooWideToFit
  </a>
  <div class="breadcrumb-separator">&raquo;</div>
  <a href="#" class="breadcrumb3 ellipsis">
    Short
  </a>
  <div class="breadcrumb-separator">&raquo;</div>
  <a href="#" class="breadcrumb3 ellipsis">
    Short
  </a>
  <div class="breadcrumb-separator">&raquo;</div>
  <a href="#" class="breadcrumb3 ellipsis">
    Short
  </a>
</div>

<div class="breadcrumbs">
  <a href="#" class="breadcrumb4 ellipsis">
    SomeLongTitleGoesHereAndItsTooWideToFit
  </a>
  <div class="breadcrumb-separator">&raquo;</div>
  <a href="#" class="breadcrumb4 ellipsis">
    Short
  </a>
  <div class="breadcrumb-separator">&raquo;</div>
  <a href="#" class="breadcrumb4 ellipsis">
    Short
  </a>
  <div class="breadcrumb-separator">&raquo;</div>
  <a href="#" class="breadcrumb4 ellipsis">
    Short
  </a>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this example with additional `max-width: min-content;` in the `.breadcrumb` class and some **flex** property changes. Without extra classes.

```css
.breadcrumb-separator {
  flex: 1 0 auto; /* changed */
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.breadcrumb {
  max-width: min-content; /* new line */
  flex: 0 1 100%; /* changed */
}
```

```css
.breadcrumbs {
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0 0 50px 0;
  padding: 5px;
}

.breadcrumb-separator {
  flex: 1 0 auto; /* changed */
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.ellipsis {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.breadcrumb {
  max-width: min-content; /* new line */
  flex: 0 1 100%; /* changed */
}
```

```html
<div class="breadcrumbs">
  <a href="#" class="breadcrumb ellipsis">
        SomeLongTitleGoesHereAndItsTooWideToFit
      </a>
  <div class="breadcrumb-separator">&raquo;</div>
  <a href="#" class="breadcrumb ellipsis"> Short </a>
  <div class="breadcrumb-separator">&raquo;</div>
  <a href="#" class="breadcrumb ellipsis"> Short </a>
  <div class="breadcrumb-separator">&raquo;</div>
  <a href="#" class="breadcrumb ellipsis"> Short </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, `max-width: min-content` is exactly what I was looking for. Changing `.breadcrumb-separator` to `flex: 1 0 auto` is not required, however.

Comment: So how does it work?

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier if you can add a class dynamically according to the length of the text content.

In that case, only give `flex-shrink` to those are too wide:

```css
.breadcrumbs {
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0 0 50px 0;
  padding: 5px;
}

.breadcrumb-separator {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.ellipsis {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.breadcrumb {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.breadcrumb.long {
  flex-shrink: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="breadcrumbs">
  <a href="#" class="breadcrumb ellipsis long">
    SomeLongTitleGoesHereAndItsTooWideToFit
  </a>
  <div class="breadcrumb-separator">&raquo;</div>
  <a href="#" class="breadcrumb ellipsis">
    Short
  </a>
  <div class="breadcrumb-separator">&raquo;</div>
  <a href="#" class="breadcrumb ellipsis">
    Short
  </a>
  <div class="breadcrumb-separator">&raquo;</div>
  <a href="#" class="breadcrumb ellipsis">
    Short
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, clear. Also it's possible to add a bit of JS logic with ResizeObserver to detect the "long" links. But it looks like the requested behavior is "natural", and flexbox was designed for tasks like that. So maybe pure css flexible solution still exists?